# Angular formGroup multiple InputControl valueChanges event by using array of property name

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

Let get into problem,

I want to register multiple input control value change event so while typing in webStorm I got an suggestion that angular form.get() take array of string or numbers [here the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXXrD.png)
. So I'm tried with this in `ngOnInit(`)

```
const props = ['customerName', 'address', 'contactNo', 'email', 'additionalDetails'];
this.invoiceForm.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
  this.invoiceForm.get(props).valueChanges.subscribe((value: string | number) => {
    console.log(value);
  });
});
```

After that I tried with this

```
this.invoiceForm.get(props).valueChanges.subscribe((value: string | number) => {
      console.log(value);
    });
```

In Both cases I got this error on my console but I didnt get any error or warning in my IDE.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'valueChanges' of null
    at InvoiceComponent.ngOnInit (invoice.component.ts:44)
    at callHook (core.js:4776)
    at callHooks (core.js:4746)
    at executeInitAndCheckHooks (core.js:4698)
    at refreshView (core.js:9153)
    at refreshEmbeddedViews (core.js:10245)
    at refreshView (core.js:9162)
    at refreshComponent (core.js:10291)
    at refreshChildComponents (core.js:8935)
    at refreshView (core.js:9188)
```

Their documentaion says

```
AbstractControl.get(path: string | (string | number)[]): AbstractControl
Retrieves a child control given the control's name or path.
Retrieve a nested control
For example, to get a name control nested within a person sub-group:
this.form.get('person.name'); -OR-
this.form.get(['person', 'name']);
```

My question is if they support to get control from form via array of control name then why I'm getting error & If I want to achive this goal how could I have solve this. Or I'm wrong.

Comment: maybe this will help https://www.zeptobook.com/how-to-listen-changes-in-reactive-form-controls-using-valuechanges-in-angular/

Comment: Sefat, you subscribe to a formGroup.valueChanges **or** to each FormControl of the FormGroup, has no sense subscribe to each control in the valueChanges of the formGroup.BTW be sure your formGroup exist and has the FomControl **before** subscribe to valueChanges

Comment: I make my own custom func to handle this please watch this code snippet is here https://www.codepile.net/pile/nvY38pq7 to achieve this in better way if I do someting wrong.TIA @Eliseo

Comment: The problem is the same, you sould call to the function **after** create the formGroup. BTW, you should check if the FormControl exist: `const control=formGroup? formGroup.get(prop):null; ìf (control) control.valueChanges.susbcribe(...)` and you has `ìf (data)...`, So, if you change the input and clear the input don't pass the "if"

Comment: now understand, thank you @Eliseo